# Does a bounty poster have any responsibilities?

Tags: discussion, bounties, accepted-answer

I recently answered a bounty question

**[Why nested ng-grid height does not work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25205911/why-nested-ng-grid-height-does-not-work/25298548?noredirect=1#comment39969164_25298548)**

I looked into github, found the part of the code that used fixed height and explained why embedded grids were not possible. I further tried to come up with a version of a nested grid that used collapsible rows to emulate.

Anyone who answers bounty questions has had cases where they feel they earned a bounty and wasn't awarded it. Part of the game and I accept it. And here I wasn't awarded (*though I got half through community rule*).

When I asked the user if I was helpful, he responded

> Thanks your co-operation. I am trying to avoid ng-grid. Because most
>   of the of my developing software object are complex. In web I could
>   not find any js grid which support such type of features.Your comments
>   is right (You're trying to build a house with a screw-driver. )

basically, user admitted that I lead him in right direction.

So, I asked:

> thanks, but then wouldnt it have made sense to accept the answer and
>   award the bounty?

The user responded by saying:

> You have already gain 25. You were directly answer by subgrid which
>   was not correct. And your answer does not solve my problem. I knew
>   that nested grid does not supported in ng-grid. But I posted such
>   problem in stackoverflow in order to aware ng-grid author or
>   contributors. Else I wanted to get ans. from community if some one
>   solved it already(in another way).

Now this answer is a little confusing. My sense is that the user didn't award me accepted answer or bounty because he didn't like the answer or the reality I was sharing with him. The part that bothers me is the part about:

> I knew that nested grid does not supported in ng-grid. But I posted such problem in stackoverflow in order to aware ng-grid author or contributors.

**Is it wrong or misleading to put a bounty on a question in hopes that the authors of a tool notice you and ignore valid answers?**

- The overall points, even if awarded are small, but I feel like I wasted my time when I wasn't the actual audience.
- Accepted Answers and awarded bounties are like gold-stars for a job well done (free of cash)
- In this case I was never the intended audience but wasted my time.

---

As I asked DanJvorak,

**does the poster have any responsibility setting guidelines so i dont waste 
hours trying to help?**

Comment: If a bounty poster wants an official response from the creators of some software, it would be nice from them if they said that in the bounty text. Other than that, I don't think there's anything you can do.

Comment: @JanDvorak, It sounds like you agree more than disagree; I'm asking  **does the poster have any responsibility setting guidelines so i dont waste many hours?** Your answer comment was it would be nice, but i'd say it's misleading and in bad taste if the posted DOES NOT indicate something so important.

Answer (score 5):

The same ethical rule for accepting an answer can also be applied here in my opinion: **there is no obligation or responsibility whatsoever**. The person who started the bounty can do whatever he/she likes with it.

If you answer just because you want the points, you are answering for the wrong reason.

True, bounty is a good incentive and it's natural to want an award, but keep in mind the main goal of the site is helping programmers in general.

If you posted a good answer you will get at least half the bounty, in addition to upvotes, which you got. This should be enough incentive.

More than that is nitpicking on the verge of being rude if you ask the bounty starter "plz give me the pointz". The word "accepted" in comments is a red flag to this very day, to allow users to nuke comments asking "mark as accepted" - and for a good reason.

Comment: I agree that helping is most important. But his response implied that I didn't really help, he knew all along, and was hoping a contributor would fix it for him. So my time was wasted utterly (points be damned) Is that wrong if it's not clearly stated?

Comment: If asking for bounty is a no-no (i see it happen a lot, ill remove it). Heck, I wana delete the whole answer. But this is less about accepting and more about **question wasnt for me at all**

Comment: @DaveA just avoid asking directly to be awarded the bounty, but please don't delete the answer. You got points for it, it is helpful for others, destroying it just as revenge does not make much sense.

Comment: I will delete the wrongful comment (after the post is closed). But the points are miniscule, and I'd like to remove the memory of the time I wasted trying to explain something the user claims he already knew on a problem I apparently wasn't supposed to answer. Wouldn't you agree that if I wasn't the target audience to answer, then deleting is appropriate? (it gets revenge on no one)

Comment: @DaveA you seem to miss the key point: when you answer in Stack Overflow, it should not be as direct help to the author of the question, it should be a general answer targeted at everyone. So "trying to explain something the user" is irrelevant. Again, if your answer got upvotes it means people found it helpful. This alone is reason enough to keep it around, no matter what the OP of the question thinks about it.

Comment: I do get that. And usually the answer is the answer and it is it's own reward. You don't get the **Unsung Hero** badge unless you help for it's own sake. Sometime's a poster's response is so petty, I want to chuck it all ;)

Comment: But your comment begs the question: If answering to earn a bounty is wrong motivation, how are you not indicting the whole bounty system? You can't have it both ways. Manishtana!

Comment: Like it or not, Bounty Hunting is a sport. like high-stakes fishing. Intentionally or not, it was developed this way.

Comment: @DaveA true, it's sport and you answer to get the points, but not purely for this goal. My point, which might not be very well explained, is that if you fail you get the bounty you should understand it's not against any ethical rules.

Comment: I think your explanation is sound, but its a contradiction between the goal of getting answers an awarding bounties that cannot be reconciled in pure terms. We have bounty ranges from 50-500 pts. We have leagues and rankings. **To deny the role of points is to turn a blind eye to the goal of Bounties** Who ever answered a 500pt bounty question for **purely community purposes?**

Comment: While I agree with the overall core of this answer, I would certainly not subscribe to *"If you answer just because you want the points, you are answering for the wrong reason"*, since that is exactly the reason why we have points. The main goal of the site might very well be helping programmers in general, but that doesn't need to be *my* goal. Views through the pink glasses aside, my *main* motivation for posting are admittedly indeed "fake internet points" and not an inherent desire to help the world. If that diminishes the value of my questions and answers is a different question, though.

Comment: +1, Your reasoning and points are sound. Insightful even.

Comment: thank you @ChristianRau. It's ok to pursue points shamelessly. The system was based on them.

Answer (score 5):

Have you ever walked by a fountain and dropped a coin into it while making a wish? That's what bounties are. There's no guarantee that you'll actually *get* your wish, and there's also no guarantee that you'll be recognized for *granting* one. That's how the wells work. The only thing that we can promise is that a question, and the answers it receives, show up on the featured tab for a bit of time.

Bounties enable others to draw your attention to certain things that they find of interest through the concept of *proof of work* - they've done some amount of (perhaps unrelated) work that is sufficient for the system to deem significant. As a courtesy and acknowledgement of their efforts, we convert the usual reward (rep) into a commodity folks can spend by enabling them to transfer it to someone else. However, it's a one-way street once someone initiates the process, and the system [*will take over*](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/16065/how-does-the-bounty-system-work) if they fail to follow through for any reason.

The whole *idea* of reputation points as a commodity can be quite unsettling when you consider a system where *every single point* should be hard-earned, because it represents the amount of trust that we as a community place in you and our combined perception of the quality of any single post. To that, bounties will always be a side deal, a contract we're not going to arbitrate, and a system that we're not going to treat as anything other than an unregulated market, barring cases of obvious abuse. The introduction of the system in more, even basic forms, was quite controversial.

Put simply, if you go hunting tigers, make *absolutely* certain that you're prepared to find a tiger :) Don't forget to consider the possibility of one eluding you, however wounded, even after you've chased it for hours.

***This doesn't excuse the usual norms***

*Questions should be clear, relatively narrowly-scoped and contain within them everything one might need to answer*. If they do *not*, then there's a potential problem with the question. Bounties were created for questions that might require *rare knowledge* to answer, be they *hard* or simply *niche*. A bounty is not a free pass for scope creep.

[Chameleon questions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/43478/exit-strategies-for-chameleon-questions) have exit strategies. Questions that have changed *so much* that their answers now seem bizarre should be closed quickly, and you'll definitely want to involve moderators for that. People sucking the *life blood* out of you in comments, bounty or not, should probably get:

> I've reached the extent that I'm willing to help you with this, I'm really busy, you should have enough now to work through this.

If you see someone *chronically* abusing the bounty system as some means to get one-on-one sessions with anyone that answers, involve a moderator.

Otherwise, these are deals that folks make on the outskirts of the system, if they're not obviously abusing the feature - no, we're not going to get involved. As in any other deal, it's a question of cutting your losses where appropriate.

Comment: I love the system. **Wouldn't change a thing**. My question was not a bout policy or enforce. It was meant to be a discussion about whether the Poster of a Bounty has any **Moral** obligation. Interesting thing about "Moral" Thoughts. They're philosophical. I seem to have done a bad job of explaining myself. But I don't equate bounties with coins in a wishing fountains. Lion hunting, maybe. To me, they're a "Moral" promise to award points to those who help them solve their problems.

Comment: Some posters take that obligation very seriously and award points to whoever comes closest even if thats not close at all). Others (I've had this happen numerous times), will allow the timeline to expire, let the user get half and then accept the answer at their convenience. Still a few others will rip and whine and complain that they "need" a "better" answer even after they've received the "best" answer possible (Can't be done the way you want and here's why). Those people are breaking an implicit contract. It's their right to do so, but it's petty.

Comment: @DaveA Common convention, at least to the extent that I follow it by trying to be both polite and civil says _yes_, but I've established that in a bit of a vacuum; if there's no arbitration beyond possible cases of abuse of the system, then .. well :)

Comment: There shouldn't be any arbitration. And I'm not asking for any. The system is as good as (I believe) it can be. This began as a question of whether the poster has any responsibility in the "deal". Even if no one enforces the right thing, that doesn't make all my actions good or right.

Comment: @DaveA I would say _yes_, they have a bit of responsibility that stems from common decency. If you set out a contract, albeit implied, and someone fulfills it, you should keep up your end. I believe that I express consensus when stating that, but I'm not certain to what end. It's okay to _not_ award a bounty, the system will do it for you in most cases, it was designed that way. You noted that you like the system precisely how it is, I'm not quite certain what you're seeking in an answer to your question.

Comment: @DaveA Or perhaps you're not seeking an end, but someone simply agreeing that not keeping up your side of a deal unless there's a clear reason why not is not only quite rude but rather indigent? Yeah, I fully agree with that. Your next experience, fortunately, should be better :)

Comment: Yes, you understand me. I'm simply looking for agreement that THERE IS IN FACT an implied contract. The poster has the freedom, but that doing so is breach of faith. -- an indignity as you put it so well! Thanks Tim

Answer (score 1):

When a poster posts a bounty, it's much like a commission on a project:

### Similarities:

- In both cases, the value of your work can be disputed.
- In all technically commissioned projects, communicating needs are challenging.

### Differences

- On Stack Overflow, the user who answer is working (1) charitably to help, (2) for pride in a job well done, and usually (3) for points,
- On Stack Overflow, we who help people accept the chance every time knowing that the user may get quality help and return nothing
- On Stack Overflow, Community rules protect bounty-hunters like me (I've been awarded 37 bounties in 50 attempts) by giving us half the "purse" if we get enough vote-ups.

#### Conclusion:

- I like our system. I agree with ***Shadow Wizard*** that the bounty poster is free choose whether to award a bounty or not.
- But as the poster is getting free labor from someone interested in helping and points, there is an *inherent moral obligation* to explain clearly the terms of "delivery" and to *reward those who have solved the poster's problem* or done the most to bring them closer.

**In particular**, I feel that a bounty poster engages in a moral contract to reward the one who answered the users stated question or helped poster move ahead by awarding a bounty and accepting an answer.

**Anything less is petty!** Hours of working are invested in helping -- in taking on the challenge of a bounty. Assuming that the OP's stated question is answered, and or help the OP gets assistance, not rewarding that person is breaking a moral promise.

In such cases, the poster is stifling someone who has helped them from the cheapest form of compensation: **recognition**.

Comment: tmb;dr (too much bold; didn't read)

Comment: @JanDvorak, removed some bold. Is it worth reading now?